# If temperature is the expected value of kinetic energy: $T\propto \text{E[}E_k\text{]}$, what is exactly entropy in statistical similar terms?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If temperature is the expected value of kinetic energy: $T\propto \text{E[}E_k\text{]}$, what is exactly entropy in terms of moments similar to expected value?

Is there a relation with moments and moment generating functions, since $$ \operatorname{E} \left[X^n\right] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n\,\mathrm{d}F(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

TL/DR:
I'm pretty sure there's no good way to define entropy in terms of an integral of a moment generating function. But we can definitely think about entropy in statistical terms. In fact, thinking about the entropy as the number of ways I can have a given thermodynamic state (with some extra algebra tacked on) is actually one of the more useful ways of thinking about entropy.

Let's take a look at the two main definitions of entropy.

1. If we ask [Clausius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem), then the CHANGE in entropy is equal to the change in heat for a reversible process divided by the temperature.

$$\Delta S = \oint_{}^{}\frac{\delta Q}{T}$$

We know that adding heat to a system both/either increases the internal energy of a system (i.e. increases T) and/or allows that system to do work. So the change of entropy is...the change in something that may or may not be related to the first moment of your kinetic energy distribution...divided by the first moment. That doesn't seem like it leads us anywhere useful.

2. If we ask [Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula), then entropy is equal to a constant times the natural log of the number of microstates available to your system.
   $$S = k_b ln(\Omega )$$

Again, no clear connection to any moment generating function. But the number of microstates in your system (the omega up there) is a VERY statistical value. It's the size of your sample space (as long as you pick the right sample space).

Think of flipping a coin for a second. If I flip a coin four times and get 3 heads, 1 tail, I'm describing the *macrostate* of my flipped-coin system. But how many different *ways* are there for me to get 3 heads and 1 tail? Well, there's {H,H,H,T},{H,H,T,H},{H,T,H,H},and {T,H,H,H}. There you go. I've just enumerated the four different *microstates* that would give me my observed macrostate. That's what that omega inside our boltzmann equation up there is looking at.

If you want more information on this setup, check out the microcanonical ensemble.